# Как изменить значение path через javascript?

Tags: javascript, svg

Есть следующий кусок кода:

```
page[i].attribute[j].nodeValue="M 60 10 V 150 H 160 V 10 Z"
```

Как сделать, чтобы туда подставлять вычисленное значение, а не статическое, как тут?

Comment: А в чем, собственно, затруднение-то? `path = <Тут каким-то образом вычисляете значение>; page[i].attribute[j].nodeValue=path;`

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `setAttribute`:

```js
var x = 10;
document.querySelector('path').setAttribute('d', 'M' + x + ',10L50,50L90,10z');
```

```html
<svg width="150" height="150"><path d="M0 0"/></svg>
```

Comment: Мне нужно реализовать на javascript. А затруднение в том, что когда я вычисляю x я его хочу туда потставить, а сделать типо. M x 10 V 150 ... Я не могу. Потому и спрашиваю как записать туда свои динамические значения

Comment: @Frodo, поправил. Вы так хотели?

Comment: @Frodo, если это то, что вы хотели, то поставьте галочку к ответу.